# I want to select all users from table (users) where user does not have a pageId = 9 in table page_members

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select using join query, but I am failing, this is how my tables look[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FCV8.png)

my query

```
select *
from users u
left join page_members p on p.userId != u.id and p.pageId = 9;
```

But I am getting all users.

Comment: Do `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: The results are the same

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images.) [mcve]

Comment: Look In my question there is an image of table data https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FCV8.png

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images or links to images.

Comment: Add `WHERE p.userId IS NULL` to your query.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you want

```
  SELECT *
   FROM users u
   LEFT JOIN page_members p ON p.userId = u.id 
        AND p.pageId <> 9;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple <> or != (they are parsed as the same operator) would only remove the information about pageID assignment. So this is not the way.

If you are only interested in users, simple

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE userID NOT IN (SELECT userID FROM page_members 
                     WHERE pageID = 9)
```

will suffice.

But if you need combined info from both tables, you have to either use the above subquery in a WHERE clause additionally to your JOIN, or use MINUS operator (but then you will end up with a spaghetti-query)

Choosing between LEFT or INNER join does not matter in this particular case. So in your case the solution would be sth like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users u 
JOIN page_members p ON (p.userId = u.userId)
WHERE u.userID NOT IN (SELECT userID FROM page_members 
                       WHERE pageID = 9)
```

Comment: Thank u so much brother, it works successfully

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.  Fix the `left join` and add `where` clause:

```
select *
from users u left join
     page_members p
     on p.userId = u.id and p.pageId = 9
where p.userId is null;   -- no match found
```